# Strange CSS positioning issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

Using [Flowslider](http://www.flowslider.com/). Please take a look [at this website](http://goo.gl/Wo2wG). The slider's positions changes by JS (AFAIK) and it gets position over content under slider. Also, as you see, getting big empty space between `h1` tag and slider div. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: The page you are trying to browse to is categorized as "Phishing". Why is that?

Comment: How do you want it to look/behave?

Comment: @SACHIN Slider must be directly under H1 and the content under slide must be visible. (but now slider gets position over content and hides it)

Comment: .www_FlowSlider_com-item remove margin form this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In slider.css, line 10:

```
.www_FlowSlider_com-item{
    margin: 32px 10px 32px 0;
}
```

This gives a margin-top of 32px on every image container. Try replacing with

```
.www_FlowSlider_com-item{
    margin: 0px 10px 32px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin from `.www_FlowSlider_com-item` class.

You will get your solution.